# Installing NS2 under Ubuntu

Tags: bash, permissions, ns2

I'm trying to install NS2 on Ubuntu 14.04. I followed the steps that are recommended and [in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/730525/how-to-run-a-tcl-script-in-ns2-when-path-in-bash-file-is-not-found). But I'm still facing lots of errors.

```
/home/smallko/ns-allinone-2.28/sgb/gb_io.w:576: undefined reference to `_fclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test_io] Error 1
Unable to create sgb library, but it's optional, so continuing...
============================================================
* Build GT-ITM
============================================================
sgb lib not found. gt-itm & sgb2ns could not be installed. Continuing..
============================================================
* Build zlib
============================================================
./install: 382: ./install: ./configure: Permission denied
Zlib-1.1.4 configuration failed, but it's optional, so continuing ...
============================================================
* Build tcl8.4.5
============================================================
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/smallko/ns-allinone-2.28/tcl8.4.5/unix/dltest/Makefile.in', needed by `Makefile'.  Stop.
./install: 409: ./install: ./configure: Permission denied
tcl8.3.2 configuration failed! Exiting ...
Tcl is not part of the ns project.  Please see www.Scriptics.com
to see if they have a fix for your platform.
```

I tried a lot but I can't fix this `Permission denied` error. Or is there another problem?

Comment: »» ./configure: Permission denied «« : Happens when a Windows© tool is used for the unpack of ns-allinone-2.28.tar.gz .... or if unpacked with 'sudo' . No root or sudo for any ns2 commands, please. ( Except for 'sudo make install' ) . .... Why use ns-2.28 ?

Comment: I have a modified version of NS2 and I need to run that exact one.

Comment: I unpacked it in Ubuntu and not Windows.

Comment: »» I have a modified version of NS2 «« :  Which protocol is it about ? .... May be you got a corrupt copy ? ... There is a solution, if you are sure you unpacked in a right way : `chmod +x configure` ...  etc. etc. all scripts with 'Permission denied'.

Comment: This copy has been tested before. I used chmod 777 but it works for a file not all files in a folder. I have lots of files in different folders.

Comment: Please tell which modified ns-2.28 it is about. Which protocol? ... I may have a perfect copy in my "ns2 warehouse". ... About { tcl8.4*, tk8.4*, otcl, tclcl } : You can use valid tcl-tk-otcl-tclcl from the original ns-allinone-2.28 .

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 : libc6, libc6-dev was "updated", and can no longer be used to build old ns2. Ubuntu **12.04.5** can be used for the most versions. But not for certain patches / changes containing old code.

The usually recommended OS for ns2 is CentOS 6.8 - i386 http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/centos.org/6.8/isos/i386/CentOS-6.8-i386-LiveCD.iso ... except for the ~4 patches requiring a 64bits OS.

---

ns-allinone-2.28, Ubuntu 12.04.5, CentOS , etc. :

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.28.tar.gz
cd ns-allinone-2.28/
patch -p0 < ns228-gcc41-64_2016-1.patch
export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34
./install
cd ns-2.28/
sudo make install
cp ns ns228-orig   (This is your backup of the original 'ns')
sudo cp ns228-orig /usr/local/bin/
```

And do not add any *PATH to .bashrc . Not required.

---

Links :

ns228 patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVWpLZFgxNl9SazA/view?usp=sharing

gcc34, Ubuntu 12*, 64bit https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRTkzQnRSNXZ6UVU/view?usp=sharing

g++34, Ubuntu 12*, 64bit https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNV3J3bnVoWGNWdG8/view?usp=sharing

NAM 64bit https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNNmtLeXhsaG5hXzQ/view?usp=sharing ... All nam http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn%27t-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2